# Method getDir in ContextWrapper not mocked [Mockito]

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test a module that uses a ContextWrapper class.

I try to mock it using this code:

```
 ContextWrapper contextWrapper = mock(ContextWrapper.class);
 File myFile = mock(File.class);
 doReturn(mFile).when(contextWrapper).getDir(anyString(), anyInt());
```

The method being tested still uses its own declaration of ContextWrapper
and return an Exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getDir in android.content.ContextWrapper not mocked
```

I've checked other entries related to this issue and I discovered that it may be due to being an exclusive Android class.

I also tried Mockito v2's

```
given(contextWrapper.getDir(AppFolders.getFolderPath(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).willReturn(mFile);
```

Edit:
Here is the module I am trying to test

```
public void send(final String id, final ErrorReport errorReport, final MyCallback callback) {
if(null == errorReport || null == errorReport.getType()){
  callback.result("Error Report Empty"));
  return;
}

try {
  processResponse(sendReport(id, errorReport),
          callback,
          new Executable() {
            @Override
            public void execute() throws Exception {
              callback.result("SUCCESS");
            }
          },
          origin);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

and
here is the module where the ContextWrapper is located

```
private MyResponse sendReport(String id, ErrorReport errorReport) throws Exception {
ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context);
AppFolders.setCustomerInfoZipFilename(id);
File logFolder = contextWrapper.getDir(AppFolders.getFolderPath(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File zipFile = new File(logFolder.getAbsolutePath() + AppFolders.getCustomerInfoZipFilename());

String zipBase64 = getBase64String(zipFile);

ErrorReportData errorReportData = new ErrorReportData();
errorReportData.setData(zipBase64);

MyResponse response = myClient.errorReport(errorReportData);
return response;}
```

And here is the test module

```
public class Send extends BaseTest{

private static final String URL_METHOD_CALL = "send/";

private File myFile;

private ContextWrapper contextWrapper;

@Test
public void when_send_response_valid_then_callback_success() throws Exception {

    ErrorReport errorReport = new ErrorReport();
    errorReport.setType(new ErrorType());

    contextWrapper = mock(ContextWrapper.class);

    myFile = mock(File.class);

    whenNew(ContextWrapper.class).withArguments(any(Context.class)).thenReturn(contextWrapper);
    doReturn(myFile).when(contextWrapper).getDir(anyString(), anyInt());


    MyResponse response = MockClient.getMockClient().submit(mockHost+URL_METHOD_CALL, StatusCode.STATUS_SUCCESS);

    doSetToken();
    when(client.errorReport(any(ErrorReportData.class), any(ClientImpl.Header.class))).thenReturn(response);
    service.send(mockUser, errorReport, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void result(Response<String> response) {
            assertEquals(StatusCode.STATUS_SUCCESS, response.getStatus());
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Add the actual method impl and also full test method impl

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the original post to include it

Comment: are u using powermockito here? do you have annotations on public class Send extends BaseTest{?

Comment: No, I am not using PowerMockito

Comment: whenNew is not in mockito api.. thats definately powermockito and you need to do some set-up if you want to use that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File myFile = mock(File.class);
when(contextWrapper.getDir(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(myFile);
```